# will a battery drain charge if connected to a breadboard open circuit and no load

Tags: batteries, circuit-analysis, breadboard

Can you please let me know practically is it possible to drain the charges of the battery if the terminals are attached to a breadboard on two different columns and without load. Ideally if its open circuit it should not.

Comment: This is really asking 'do batteries leak their charge' and yes, they all do. Check the datasheet for your battery.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. As a practical matter, it should drain no more than if the battery were sitting in it's package.